# Windows: setting security attributes at process-level granularity

Tags: windows, service, windows-vista, vista-security

Background: I have a windows service that works in the background (obviously), and uses
  a utility program to perform a certain interactive task and send back the data
  to the service over a named pipe. The utility program runs whenever the service
  sees fit, and lives only for a few seconds.

The problem begins in Vista where the program could not freely open the named pipe
for write access anymore (see [Windows Service Hardening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_and_safety_features_new_to_Windows_Vista#Windows_Service_Hardening)).

I plan to solve the problem by creating the named pipe with security attributes
such that grant write-access to the currently logged-in user under whos context
the program is started, while a question rose to my mind:
Could I allow access to that named pipe to only the *process* using its (or its thread's)
handle?

Or to put differently: Can windows' (Vista/7/later) security mechanism go down to
process-level granularity?

I'm a novice in that area and the docs about security are giving me quite a headache, so any enlightenment is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't secure an object via process id (because processes are not security principals), but you can use `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` after the connection is established, and fail all requests if the process id is not one you like.